# injecting html to another element by html() or append() using jq the injected elements cant be accessed by jq but with JS it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code :

```
//This works
$("#addNew").click(function(){
    $("#Q_countainer").append("<img class='MyClassName' src='0369.png' >");
});
//This doesn't work
$(".MyClassName").click(function(){
    alert("HERE")
});
//This doesn't work either
$(document).on("click",".MyClassName",function(){
    alert("HERE")   
});
```

The first section adds an image inside an element with `id="Q_countainer"`. The second and third section can't detect the `img` by class or id or name or anything.

Comment: Which jQuery version do you use? Also do you have other click handlers on your `#Q_countainer`?

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/sekxggq6/ here.

Comment: it seems to be working just fine: see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gvsaq7s/) although @laruiss answer is better implementation.

Comment: it should work, have you added your coed in $(document).ready() ??

Comment: Actually, the `$(".MyClassName").click(...)` cannot behave as expected since when this part of code is being exectued, the `<img class='MyClassName' src='0369.png' >` won't exist, but the delegated event will surely work as is (hence I didn't touch it in my answer).

Comment: Thanks everybody. it solved. it was about my jq version. i renewed it and it worked . thank you all : @S.Pols And Others

Answer (score 3):

```
//This works
$("#addNew").click(function(){
    //This does work, but...
    $('<img class="MyClassName" src="0369.png">')
      .appendTo($("#Q_countainer"))
      .click(function(){
        alert("HERE 1");
    });
});

// ... this is better (this will work only *after* #addNew will have been clicked)
// This is called delegated events and is a good practice.
$(document).on("click",".MyClassName",function(){
    alert("HERE 2");
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dzLt1mp1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should be doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addNew").click(function(){
        $("#Q_countainer").append("<img class='MyClassName' src='0369.png' >");
    });

    $(document).on("click",".MyClassName",function(){
        alert("HERE");  
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/30/)

```
//This doesn't work
$(".MyClassName").click(function(){
    alert("HERE")
});
```

This doesn't work since the element is being created dynamically, [**event delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is required in such cases. Plus you were missing semicolons in the alert statements.